# Bcrypt didn't assign the hashed password to body.password variable

Tags: node.js, express, bcrypt

```js
module.exports.handle_sign_up = async (req,res) => {
    let body = req.body

    await bcrypt.hash(body.password, 10, (err,hash) => {
        body.password = hash
        console.log(hash)
    })

    res.send(body)
};
```

Above is my code which hashes body.password using bcrypt. I tried to assign the hashed password to body.password in callback function but when res.send(body) executed it instead returns unhashed password meanwhile when I tried to console.log(hash) the hashed password it succesfully  log the hashed password to the console. Is there any problem that cause this?

Comment: most of the beginners to `async and await ` do the same mistake,you need to store the promise to resolve or reject it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
module.exports.handle_sign_up = async (req,res) => {
    let body = req.body
    let hashedPassword;     
     try{
       hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(body.password,10);
       body.password = hashedPassword;
       console.log(hashedPassword,body.password);
     }catch(err){
       console.log(err)
    })

    res.send(body)
};
```

- This is one way to do with `try and catch`
- to do with callbacks

```
 module.exports.handle_sign_up = async (req,res) => {
    let body = req.body
         
     
      bcrypt.hash(body.password,10)
       .then((hashedPassword) => {
             body.password = hashedPassword;
          })
          .catch(err => console.log(err))
     

    res.send(body)
};
```

- the mistake which you have done , is `await` returns a promise, if you dont store it , it is left as a promise which is not resolved
- to resolve it , you need to store the promise, and then use `then and catch`

Comment: This solve my problem and thanks a lot for helpful explanation!